Loading gltf via bpy in headless mode crashes while UI works
I have been trying to import a .gltf file into belnder via python script using bpy.
bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath)

I ran the script using the next command:
blender -b --factory-startup -P import_into_blender.py

But blender crashes and exits due to an invalid vertex/mesh data in .gltf file with the next error:
RuntimeError: Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py", line 2060, in unit_import
    BlenderGlTF.create(gltf_importer)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_gltf.py", line 35, in create
    BlenderGlTF._create(gltf)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_gltf.py", line 42, in _create
    BlenderScene.create(gltf)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_scene.py", line 35, in create
    BlenderNode.create_vnode(gltf, 'root')
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_node.py", line 46, in create_vnode
    BlenderNode.create_vnode(gltf, child)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_node.py", line 46, in create_vnode
    BlenderNode.create_vnode(gltf, child)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_node.py", line 46, in create_vnode
    BlenderNode.create_vnode(gltf, child)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_node.py", line 32, in create_vnode
    obj = BlenderNode.create_object(gltf, vnode_id)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_node.py", line 53, in create_object
    obj = BlenderNode.create_mesh_object(gltf, vnode)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_node.py", line 273, in create_mesh_object
    mesh = BlenderMesh.create(gltf, pynode.mesh, pynode.skin)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_mesh.py", line 26, in create
    return create_mesh(gltf, mesh_idx, skin_idx)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_mesh.py", line 47, in create_mesh
    do_primitives(gltf, mesh_idx, skin_idx, mesh, tmp_ob)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/imp/gltf2_blender_mesh.py", line 185, in do_primitives
    vert_locs = np.concatenate((vert_locs, vs[unique_indices]))
                                           ~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: index 16036 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 496
Location: /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.1/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:109

... truncated
Blender quit

My question is related to a difference in behaviour when importing same file via UI.
Why does Blender import file successfully compared to bpy and python script even though it still throws the same error?

Blender version: Blender 4.1.1 (hash e1743a0317bc built 2024-04-16
00:06:22)
OS: macOS 14.1 (23B74)
GLTF is generated via Autodesk Platform Service.


Have you tried other gltf files besides this one?  It could be a problem with the model file itself.  Headless mode should work in general because it's used to implement unit tests for the glTF importer/exporter in Blender.

@emackey Yes, I already found the problem, it was a corrupted gtlf file. But it does not explain why UI can load it while headless mode throws an error. I am still curious what is the difference.

It would take some Python debugging to understand a detailed reason why.  But generally, corrupted files can produce undefined behavior.  As long as it works for valid files, don't worry too much over it.
